# Pasar valor de @Html.Checkbox vía @Ajax.ActionLink ASP. NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net, mvc, checkbox

Tengo 3 ActionLinks y un checkbox en un Razor:

```
<li><span>Ordenar por:</span></li>
    <li>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Nombre", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = "name", pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = ""}, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading-container", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "contenedor-catalogo", OnSuccess = "loadImages()" }, new { @class = "btn " + ((ViewBag.OrderBy != null && ViewBag.OrderBy != "" && ViewBag.OrderBy != "name") ? defaultType : selectedType) + " btn-xs js-data-order btn-order _default", @data_order_id = "name" })
    </li>
    <li>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Categoría", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = "category", pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = "" }, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading-container", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "contenedor-catalogo", OnSuccess = "loadImages()" }, new { @class = "btn " + ((ViewBag.OrderBy == null) ? defaultType : (ViewBag.OrderBy == "category") ? selectedType : defaultType) + " btn-xs js-data-order btn-order", @data_order_id = "category" })
    </li>
    <li>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Precio", "Index", "Productos", new { orderby = "price", pagenumber = 0, category = @ViewBag.Category, keywords = @ViewBag.Keywords, orderType = "" }, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loading-container", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "contenedor-catalogo", OnSuccess = "loadImages()" }, new { @class = "btn " + ((ViewBag.OrderBy == null) ? defaultType : (ViewBag.OrderBy == "price") ? selectedType : defaultType) + " btn-xs js-data-order btn-order", @data_order_id = "price" })
    </li> <li>
        @Html.CheckBox("MostrarImagen", true, new { @onchange = "OnValueChanged();" })
        <input id="MostrarImagen" name="MostrarImagen" value="false" type="checkbox" style="display:none" />
    </li>
```

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando presione el actionlink se mande el estado actual del checkbox (si esta seleccionado o no),

este es mi actionresult:

```
public ActionResult Index(int ? PageNumber, string OrderBy, string category, string keywords, string orderType, bool MostrarImagen = true)
    {//codigo...}
```

ya intente hacerlo con viewbag, viewdata y TempData, el problema que tengo es que como se manda a llamar una vista parcial y los actionlinks y el checkbox no pertenecen a esa vista parcial cuando llega el viewbag, viewdata o tempdata llegan vacíos, lo cual provoca que cuando se llega al actionresult se ponga por defecto el true siempre que selecciona alguno, o tal vez esté equivocado y no sea ese el motivo (buscando es lo que me dieron a entender), entonces necesito ayuda para poder pasar el estado actual del checkbox, alguna idea de como pueda lograr esto?

Editado:

Antes que nada mencionare que los actionlinks y el checkbox están en una vista llamada Index y el cuerpo en un partialview llamado _Catalogos, en el Index tengo el código mencionado antes (el primero) y en medio de index tengo esto:

```
<div class="container">

<!--Sección listado catálogos-->
<div class="flex-row row" id="contenedor-catalogo">
    @Html.Partial("_Catalogo")
</div>

@* Contenedor que incluye Loader 1 y el componente para mostrar los mensajes de error. *@
<div class="container-result">
    <div id="pre-loader"><div class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' style='font-size:24px'></i></div></div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="error-msg"><p>Ocurrío un error al obtener la información.</p></div>
</div>
```

Donde se observa que llamo a la partialview _Catalogo.

No puedo usar los viewbag ni sus parecidos por esto:

Cuando se seleccionan los actionlinks en mi actionresult tengo que si es llamado por un ajax (Request.IsAjaxRequest) se manda a llamar solo la vista parcial que es _Catalogo, entonces tengo entendido que los viewbag solo funcionan en la primera vista que se toca después de salir del actionresult por lo tanto si pongo en el actionlink el parámetro "MostrarImagen = @ViewBag.MostrarImagen" el viewbag está vacío, entonces no se si lo estoy usando mal o algo.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que quieres mandar llamar un partialView dependiendo de si el usuario le da clic o no al checkbox?

Comment: no, perdón por no explicarme bien, simplemente quiero que el valor que tenga actualmente mi checkbox (ischecked digamos eso) se mande por medio de los action links que tengo arriba, simplemente quiero que respete el estado actual del checkbox, porque como lo tengo ahora si el checkbox esta en false (no está seleccionado) al actionresult le llega diciendo que está en true (seleccionado), eso solo pasa con los actionlinks, porque si selecciono el checkbox el onchange actúa correctamente, no se si me explique mejor ahora.

Comment: Sucede que el checkbox manda true sólo si está marcado, sino, no lo envía, mira el HTML que genera Razor y entenderás lo que te digo

Comment: Entonces que podría hacer para mandarlo correctamente? porque intente de esta forma en el controller:
ViewBag.MostrarImagen = MostrarImagen; 
y luego en el index mandaba en el action link MostrarImagen = ViewBag.MostrarImagen, 
y pues no funciona, entonces que debería hacer?